# Serializer for fetchiing data from multiple classes

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

Environment is `Python` and `Django3`

I want to make api which retrieve the data from multiple model class.

I have models like this , each CountryStat has Country.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=3,unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class CountryStat((models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True,blank =True)
    stat = models.IntegerField()
```

Now I want to get the latest `Coutry Stat` for each `Country`.

So I made the serializer for Country

```
class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): 
    latest_stat = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = ('id','code','latest_stat')
    def get_latest_stat(self,obj):
        # how can I get the latest stat from CountryStat model ????
```

Is this the correct idea or how can I make it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a custom `latest_stat` attribute on your model:

```py
class Country(models.Model):
  code = models.CharField(max_length=3,unique=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
  
  def latest_stat(self):
    return self.countrystat_set.order_by('-date').first()
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I see I should change the model `Country`,  but here `self.countrystats`, `Country` doesn't have the `countrystats`. `CountryStat` has `Country` though, for API I want to return the json based on each country.

Comment: `Country` has `countrystats`, it is a default `related_name` for a foreign key. I.e. when you set `country = models.ForeignKey(Country, ...)` it creates `countrystats` attribute on `Country`

Comment: mmm, I see but `Exception raised in callable attribute "latest_stat"; original exception was: 'Country' object has no attribute 'countrystats'` tis errors...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I think it's `countrystat_set` by default, I updated my anwer

Comment: Wow it works perfect with  `_set`. thank you very much for your precise information.